# Public dynamic IP address

Tags: domain, dynamic-ip, ddns

I have bought a domain from "domain.com", but I have problem updating my newly given IP address from ISP every 14h. How can I use DynDNS service to work with different IPs. DynDNS need to update the ips on "domain.com".

**Eding/Update**

"domain.com" does not work with DynDNS that time, find a different approach, http://noip.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most reliable situation would be to setup a `CNAME` for a subdomain of (host on) your domain pointing to the domain you are updating with DynDNS.  I'll assume your domain is `example.com` below.

There are a variety of services that will support dynamically updating domains. Using a `CNAME` for your domain is not a supported configuration.  If you want it for access to your home system you could setup `home.domain.com` as a `CNAME` pointing the name updated by DynDNS.

You may be able to find a redirection server which can redirect web requests for your domain to your web subdomain.  Requests for `example.com` would be redirected to `www.example.com`.  If you want a reliable web server, you likely need to find a hosting provider.   If you have a hosting provider, you may be able to configure your domain's `A` record to the same IP address as you use for your web service.  Another alternative is not to publish any addresses for your domain, and just have addresses for your subdomains.  Browsers may try for a `www` subdomain in this case.

DynDNS no longer offers free services.  When it did, I had a CNAME in my domain's DNS like `home.example.com` which pointed to my DynDNS entry (`mydomain.dyndns.org`).  I've had a fixed IP address for years, so I haven't worked with the paid service.  My `www` and `mail` subdomains were hosted elsewhere and I provided `A` records for those servers.  My web provider supported my domain as well as the `www` subdomain, so I provided an `A` record for my domain with the same address as the `www` subdomain.

If you want email services, you will have problems using dynamic IP address.  Many domains will refuse to accept mail from you, and you risk loosing incoming mail.

Comment: You saying to make a CNAME for subdomain on <http://domain.com> - from original domain where i buy my (example.com) pointing to subdomain on DynDNS that iv got free (sub.example.com) or it is vice versa ?

Comment: @IvanAK you would have a CNAME record on <domain.com> for `sub.example.com` (your domain) pointing `yourdomain.dyndns.org`.

Comment: Yes i already did this thanks. But now when i go to, for example sub.example.com ( or exampl.com ) it will go to the mydomain.dynds.org that is my IP address ( from ISP that i have, public ip address ) but in the browser the name is not ( example.com ) it is mydomain.dynds.org ... is there any chance the name be the same ???

What i have done for now is this: on no-ip/dyndns i have made sub-domain that have my public IP address from the ISP, on domain.com i make CNAME that say ... example.com to point on sub.mydomain.no-ip/dyndns.org or what every it is the sub.domain.

Comment: @IvanAK  The displayed name should be the name your web server presents.  If you are running Apache, the name should be what you specified in the `ServerName` directive.  Apache also support rewrite rules to redirect to the desired domain.  The browser name should be `sub.example.com` not `example.com`.  The CNAME should be effectively invisible to the browser.

Comment: "The browser name should be sub.example.com not example.com. The CNAME should be effectively invisible to the browser." -- you saying that i have to go revers? If in my browser go to sub.example.com to show me the example.com ? is it possible all this to work behind like i did ... when i go to example.com on the browser, the name to stay that way ( example.com) but to point to the sub.example.com which is my public IP from ISP?

Comment: @IvanAK You can't have example.com on a dynamic IP using a CNAME.  This is only possible id you can dynamically update your DNS servers.  sub.example.com should be the name you use to access the content you want to share.  If you don't have another web service, you can use `www` instead of `sub` and browsers should find the content for your domain.  Define this as the name in your web server, not the name you use with DynDNS.

Comment: Yup iv got this, i just do this little experiment and i make this opposite way,in original domain.com (where example.com is) in the Cpanel in the CNAME part i make example.com to show to mypc.no-ip.org (which have my public IP) and for a minute - three it works:) strange but it works.When in my browser go to example.com, the name stays and it shows me what i have on my Server.I was too happy :D.But now its back on the old host who is from domain.com.I guess you are write, the only solution here i look is to transfer the domain (example.com) to service that have and can work with Dynamic IP.

Comment: And also iv try your way ... in domain.com i make subdomain called home.example.com and in the CNAME part i point that home.example.com to point to myserver.no-ip.org ( which is my public IP address ) and still nothing .. when i go to my browser it show me "Forbidden--You don't have permission to access / on this server."